# Get all row data when clicked on ribbon button

Tags: dynamics-crm, ribbon, crm-ribbon-workbench

I am trying to get all the fields of the selected rows on clicking of a ribbon button. So far I'm getting these values when I use `SelectedControlSelectedItemReferences` crm parameter on custom JS action:  Id (Guid), TypeCode, TypeName (Schema Name of entity) and Name.

How can I get all the fields of the selected row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only get Id (Guid), TypeCode, TypeName (Schema Name of entity) and Name. from the Grid Row. [blog for reference](https://passion4dynamics.com/2019/01/31/get-selected-record-information-from-main-view-or-a-subgrid-in-dynamics-365/)

You will have to retrieve(webapi) specific fields using guid and schema name.

Comment: This is not working for me.  Im getting undefined.  I did post question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68353084/passing-crm-parameters-though-ribbon-workbench-custom-button-to-javascript-funct